# How can i save case for field in data class in kotlin during serialization?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I just recently started to write code on kotlin and now my task is serialize some simple data class using jakson. I use this code for serializing:

```
inline fun<T> serialize(obj: T): String {
            return ObjectMapper()
                    .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
                    .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                    .registerKotlinModule()
                    .writeValueAsString(obj)
        }
```

And everything working fine except for fields case. I serialize this class:

```
data class Vac (
    var I : List<Double>,
    var v: List<Double>
)
```

And as result i got

```
{"v":[-0.0560859188544154,-0.07260127150977624],"i":[2.99850074962508E-7,1.9344277457276516E-7]}
```

i.e. case doesnt save. I extected to see filed 'I' in upper case like in class, but i got lower case. Anyone can tell me how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set the property name using `@JsonProperty("NAME")`

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
data class Vac (
    @JsonProperty("I") var I : List<Double>,
    var v: List<Double>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer! May be you know some another solution? In my code i want to make models classes maximum simply and move all serialization logic to serializer